# XMLDocument nodes have no values

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd

When I load an XML with TXMLDocument, the elements contain no values. I read the following  [example file](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xml/UBL-Invoice-2.1-Example.xml) with the element `<cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>`, it does find the node, but it doesn't recognize it as an text element and the value is empty and there are no child elements.

```
  aNode := XMLDocument1.ChildNodes.Last.ChildNodes.Nodes['ID'];
  if Assigned(aNode)  then begin
    MEMOInfo.Lines.Add('Node is found');
    MEMOInfo.Lines.Add( anode.DOMNode.nodeName);
    MEMOInfo.Lines.Add( anode.DOMNode.nodeValue);
    MEMOInfo.Lines.Add( inttostr(anode.DOMNode.nodetype));
  end;
```

this is the result

> Node is found
>   ID
>
> 1

Original question :

I created a XML Data binding from an xsd. namely UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd. I followed [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_the_XML_Data_Binding_Wizard) tutorial.

I then used [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Code_That_the_XML_Data_Binding_Wizard_Generates) tutorial to open the [example](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xml/UBL-Invoice-2.1-Example.xml) invoice file. And the file is loaded in the interface.

```
var
  Invoice:IXMLInvoiceType;
begin
  try   
    invoice := LoadInvoice('invoice-exameple.xml');  
  except
    on e:exception do begin
      MEMO.Lines.Add(e.Message);
    end;
  end;   
end;
```

Now I don't know how to acces the nodes, for example `<cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>` i would try to acces its text field but it is empty.

```
MEMO.Lines.Add('Factuurnummer : '+ invoice.ID.Text);
```

**Q** : All elements are empty, so how do I read this XML File?

Comment: There's no error messages and the object is simply empty...

Comment: yes ,no error message and all of the properties are blank/empty

Comment: What happens when you use the `Text` attribute instead of `nodeValue`?

Comment: text is also empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XMLDocument doesn't process the namespaces correct so I had to adjust the XML-File and remove the namespace.

```
<cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>
```

became

```
<ID>TOSL108</ID>
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DOM level 1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1950641247), `nodeValue` returns *null* on an element node:

> The attributes nodeName, nodeValue and attributes are included as a mechanism to get at node information without casting down to the specific derived interface. In cases where there is no obvious mapping of these attributes for a specific nodeType (e.g., nodeValue for an Element or attributes for a Comment), this returns null.

I would suggest to navigate to the child text node of this element node, and call `nodeValue` on this text node instead.

Comment: Well it also has no childnodes, but the you think the problem is it sees al the nodes as element nodes instead of text nodes?

Comment: But does the lib he uses follow the spec? The documentation for `IXMLNode.NodeValue` (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.NodeValue) says that if the `NodeType = ntElement` then **If the element contains only text, this is that text value. Otherwise, trying to read or set NodeValue causes an exception.**

Comment: That's a good question and I assumed so because of the `DOMNode` property. The same documentation refers explicitly to the W3C recommendation as well on the `DOMNode` page: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.DOMNode